# How to make counters for irregular integral pattern?

Tags: digital-circuits, sequential-circuit

I can easily make counter for consecutive numbers. But for patterns, described in below question, I'm quite unsure about my approach.

> **Question** - We want to design a synchronous counter that counts the sequence $0−1−0−2−0−3$ and then repeats. The minimum number of $J-K$ flip-flops required to implement this counter is _____________ ?

My approach - Make counter using 3 flip flops using some gates. The counting sequence $(ABC)$ would be $000, 001, 100,  010, 110, 011$ and at any state if $Y = A'B'C' + AC'$ is true output $0$, else output the current state value.

Is this approach correct? If it's not,  what's the correct approach to make counters for this kind of irregular patterns?

Comment: This feels like a programming question to me. Community votes, please: offtopic?

Comment: How programming question? @Raphael :O ... It's straight question - how to make counters for irregular patterns. If you are taking this question an analogy with a programming question, then you may be wrong.